# How to Display 1 of 2 parameters passed in URL with htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wampserver

Currently I have some.htaccess code that redirects

```
localhost/category.php?id=something&phrase=whatever
```

to

```
localhost/id/phrase
```

What I want to do now is add additional code that will only display one of those parameters in the URL for a different page called article.php So it would just be

```
localhost/article/id
```

Notice that I want the phrase parameter from the above URL to be cut out, and only the id portion to be displayed. Here's currently the complete code that I have in my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from /category.php?id=name&phrase=something to /name/something
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+category\.php\?id=([^&]+)&phrase=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=302,L]

# skip files and directories from rewrites
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Cleans up all the article, and wrestler pages
RewriteRule ^/?article/([^/]+)/?$ article.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?wrestler/([^/]+)/?$ wrestler.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

# Removes the .php extension from pages
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ category.php?id=$1&phrase=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Any thoughts guys?

Comment: Which part is not working ?

Comment: It's fully working. I simply want to add additional code that will let me display just one parameter in a URL like localhost/article/id and leave out the phrase part of the parameter. Read the question.

Comment: Well that's the problem. I read your question but it's not clear enough

Comment: Simplest terms: what .htaccess code should I write to turn something like localhost/article.php?id=something&number=10 into just localhost/id

Comment: Add this rule at the end: `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ article.php?id=$1&number=10 [L]`

Comment: The number won't always be 10 though, it could be any number.

Comment: Since you have only `id` parameter in your url, you can't pass a variable number. What represents that number ? Maybe you could cover it with server-side language (php, etc)

Comment: Can't I just pass it as a string, and then convert it to integer after? Anyway to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Most folks do something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ router_script.php?/$1 [L]
```

And then their router script does something like:

```
$args = explode('/', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
switch($args[0]) {
  case 'articles':
    $_GET['id'] = isset($args[1]) ? $args[1] : '';
    include "articles.php";
  break;
}
```

There are more elegant approaches out there, but this might do the trick.